# How to pause a video animation in video editor

Tags: animation, edit-mode, video

I am trying to create a technical animation where i require a video to pause at specific intervals to include explanation texts. For example, in the image below i require a cut to be done exactly where the blue line is:
[image]

I am aware using keyboard shortcut "K" allows for me to split strips where i can split the video, followed by splitting the image apart from the video as such:
[image]

However, when i scrub to the portions where the portion is black no video will be playing.

Tl;dr: How do i **easily** pause an animation such that i can add other edits in the other channels while keeping a still frame in the original video.

(the only brute force method i can think of currently is duplicating that still frame that i cut [2nd image] for the whole duration of the blank space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to split the strip using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then ...

just grab the right end of the left strip with your cursor and move it to the right. Then the last pic will be shown as long as you dragged the right edge.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work. When i do that, it continues the clip from where I stopped instead of holding the last frame.

Comment: you are right, sorry, i updated my answer